# How to sort filter values in descending order in SSAS tabular pivot?

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot, ssas-tabular

I have a calendar table in my SSAS Tabular model with a "Risk Month Name" column sorted by "Risk Month Number" column.

[image]

Having that config gives me month names sorted in the ascending order in the connected pivot table.

[image]

I'm trying to sort month names in the pivot filter in descending order.

I understand that I can create an extra calculated column with some values already sorted in the descending order and use this column as a sorting column for the "Risk Month Name" values.
But doing this feels wrong and extra complicated for such a simple requirement.

Is there any setting to do it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

If you change your RiskMonthNumber column to have a negative sign in front of it the sort order should reverse as you are expecting. If RiskMonthNumber is visible to users then create another hidden column for this purpose.

Comment: Actually, i like the idea :) It's very similar to having extra-special column for sorting but without having it. Unfortunately, in my case "RiskMonthNumber" column is accessible and visible for clients as a simplified numeric version of "Risk Month Name" so it wont work

Comment: Just add a new column called RiskMonthNameSort and hide it

Comment: There are so many "just" things in SSAS you need to do to <just> do something very simple that it hurts. I was hoping for some desc-checkbox somewhere :)

Comment: @AndreyMorozov I hear you. If I have answered your question please make sure to click the checkmark to indicate to the community this question is answered.

Comment: should I check all answers on all my questions or just yours? :) Maybe there will be other answers do you think?

Comment: @AndreyMorozov if you are satisfied with the answer then mark it as the answer. You can change it later if someone adds a new superior answer later